# Casting an object to an interface throws to an exception

Tags: c#, class, interface, casting

I'm trying to cast a class to an interface. And I get this exception.

I tried to watch to all used elements, but all seems to be ok.

![code exception]https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTdQu.png
And my code for IStocarePacienti interface is:

```
namespace DataAccess
{
    public interface IStocarePacienti : IStocareFactory
    {
        List<Pacient> GetPacienti();
        Pacient GetPacient(int id);
        bool AddPacient(Pacient d);

        bool UpdatePacient(Pacient d);
    }
}
```

And for my class :

```
namespace DataAccess
{
    public class AdministrarePacienti : IStocareFactory
    {
        private const int PRIMUL_TABEL = 0;
        private const int PRIMA_LINIE = 0;

        public List<Pacient> GetPacienti()
        {
            var result = new List<Pacient>();
            var dsCompanii = SqlDBHelper.ExecuteDataSet("select * from pacienti_ac", CommandType.Text);

            foreach (DataRow linieDB in dsCompanii.Tables[PRIMUL_TABEL].Rows)
            {
                result.Add(new Pacient(linieDB));
            }
            return result;
        }

        public Pacient GetPacient(int id)
        {
            Pacient result = null;
            var dsCompanii = SqlDBHelper.ExecuteDataSet("select * from pacienti_ac where ID_PACIENT = :ID_PACIENT", CommandType.Text,
                new OracleParameter(":ID_PACIENT", OracleDbType.Int32, id, ParameterDirection.Input));

            if (dsCompanii.Tables[PRIMUL_TABEL].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow linieDB = dsCompanii.Tables[PRIMUL_TABEL].Rows[PRIMA_LINIE];
                result = new Pacient(linieDB);
            }
            return result;
        }

        public bool AddPacient(Pacient comp)
        {
            return SqlDBHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(
                "INSERT INTO pacienti_ac VALUES (seq_pacienti_ac.nextval, :NUME, :PRENUME, :TELEFON, :GR_SANGUINA, :CNP, :DATA_NASTERII)", CommandType.Text,
                new OracleParameter(":NUME", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, comp.Nume, ParameterDirection.Input),
                new OracleParameter(":PRENUME", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, comp.Prenume, ParameterDirection.Input),
                new OracleParameter(":TELEFON", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, comp.Telefon, ParameterDirection.Input),
                new OracleParameter(":GR_SANGUINA", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, comp.GrSanguina, ParameterDirection.Input),
                new OracleParameter(":CNP", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, comp.CNP, ParameterDirection.Input),
                new OracleParameter(":DATA_NASTERII", OracleDbType.Date, comp.DataNasterii, ParameterDirection.Input));
        }

        public bool UpdatePacient(Pacient comp)
        {
            return SqlDBHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(
                "UPDATE pacienti_ac set NUME = :NUME, PRENUME = :PRENUME, TELEFON = :TELEFON, GR_SANGUINA = :GR_SANGUINA, CNP = :CNP, DATA_NASTERII = :DATA_NASTERII where ID_PACIENT = :ID_PACIENT", CommandType.Text,
                new OracleParameter(":NUME", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, comp.Nume, ParameterDirection.Input),
                new OracleParameter(":PRENUME", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, comp.Prenume, ParameterDirection.Input),
                new OracleParameter(":TELEFON", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, comp.Telefon, ParameterDirection.Input),
                new OracleParameter(":GR_SANGUINA", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, comp.GrSanguina, ParameterDirection.Input),
                new OracleParameter(":CNP", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, comp.CNP, ParameterDirection.Input),
                new OracleParameter(":ID_PACIENT", OracleDbType.Int32, comp.IdPacient, ParameterDirection.Input));
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know what I can do. As I said, all looks good to me.

Comment: Aren't you trying to cast it to an interface that it doesn't implement?

Comment: I do not see Store Factory anywhere ? can you provide us all implementation

Comment: StocareFactory is empty. Like:     public interface IStocareFactory
    {

    }

Comment: Are you intending to cast all of `new StocareFactory().GetTipStocare(typeof(Pacient))` to `IStocarePacienti`, or just the `new StocareFactory()`?

Comment: All of it. new StocareFactory().GetTipStocare(typeof(Pacient))

Comment: The error message you're getting is text. Please put that text in your question. It's not necessary to link to a picture. That makes people look back and forth from the picture to the code.

Comment: `AdministrarePacienti` implements `IStocareFactory`. It does not implement `IStocarePacienti`. That's why you can't cast it as `IStocarePacienti`. It doesn't matter that the class has the methods defined in the interface. It has to actually say that it implements the interface. Change `: IStocareFactory` to `: IStocarePacienti`.

Comment: Scott, you are right. Thanks!